# I am using a div to display a banner image, using the CSS background-image property, its not working in IE11 and Firefox 27.01

Tags: css, image, html

I am using Microsoft webmatrix running on a localhost, and for some reason the website displays fine in google chrome but the div with the banner image does not display in IE or Firefox.

The reason I am going with the div as a container for the image is because when I tried using img src within the parent div, I got a bug error telling me that I cannot nest an image within a div.

```
<div id="banner"></div>

#banner { background-image:url('salvationarmy2.png'); display: block; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;  width: 996px; padding: 0px;}
```

I also tried giving the div a class called image and then with css I added the content property with the url but it still gave me the same result

Comment: Have you tried giving the div a height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `div` does not contain any content its height will be `0`.  Try specifying the height for the `div`:

```
#banner {
    height: 30px; 
    background-image:url('salvationarmy2.png');  
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;  
    width: 996px; 
    padding: 0px;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HhMt5/)

Comment: thanks, it works now. but is it normal that if i use the content property instead of background-image that it should not display either? do i also have to specify a height in that case?

Answer (score 3):

you need to give your dive a hight

```
#banner {
 background-image:url('salvationarmy2.png'); 
 display: block;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 width: 996px;
 padding: 0px;
 height:200px;
}
```